# Every other row starting point in SQL SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by

Right now I'm using a SELECT that gets every 3 rows in a table. But I'm having issues starting at a specific point instead of at the end.

How can I start in the middle of the table?

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ( 
           SELECT @row := @row +1 AS `ID`
           FROM ( SELECT @row :=0 ) r, `table` ) 
        ranked WHERE id %3=1 ORDER BY `ID` DESC LIMIT 10";
```

Comment: try something like LIMIT 10, 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously stated by @dandavis you need to use both parameters available for [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html); the parameters are

1. offset
2. row_count

Bizarrely it is the *first* parameter that is optional! Therefore if you want to limit the returned rows to 10 but start at row 20 you would use:

```
LIMIT 20, 10
```